Expressing equivariant Chern character like the character of a representation
Sometimes one sees the $G$-equivariant Chern character of a $G$-equivariant vector bundle $E \to X$ expressed much like the character of a representation of $G$, as $$ ch_G(E) = \sum_i e^{a_i} $$ where the $a_i$ are elements of the dual Lie algebra $\mathfrak g^\vee$. What facilitates this identification? Under what assumptions can one do this?
